# How can I convert serial numbers to hourly timesteps?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a serial number column in a dateframe:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
.
.
216
```

And I want to create this column automatically. Basically, I want to mention the first time step (2015-05-23 00:00:00), and after that it should add 1 hour to every timestep depending on how many hours are required (here 216)

```
2015-05-23 00:00:00
2015-05-23 01:00:00
2015-05-23 02:00:00
2015-05-23 03:00:00
2015-05-23 04:00:00
.
.
2015-06-01 00:00:00
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df$num` is your variable, which has a length of `216`, then

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2015-05-23 00:00:00")
seq(start, start + length(df$num) * 60*60, by = "hour")
```

Answer (score 0):

'timeDate' plus a 'difftime'-sequence is a 'timeDate'-sequence:

```
df <- data.frame( t = NA, n = 0:12 )
t0 <- timeDate( "2015-05-23 00:00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S" )
df$t <- t0 + as.difftime( 0:(nrow(df)-1), units="hours")
```

Result:

```
> df
                     t  n
1  2015-05-23 00:00:00  0
2  2015-05-23 01:00:00  1
3  2015-05-23 02:00:00  2
4  2015-05-23 03:00:00  3
5  2015-05-23 04:00:00  4
6  2015-05-23 05:00:00  5
7  2015-05-23 06:00:00  6
8  2015-05-23 07:00:00  7
9  2015-05-23 08:00:00  8
10 2015-05-23 09:00:00  9
11 2015-05-23 10:00:00 10
12 2015-05-23 11:00:00 11
13 2015-05-23 12:00:00 12
```